# Add an "Answering Questions" Section to the Tour

Tags: feature-request, help-center

### Background to This Request

I recently answered a question for a new user, who then replied to my answer with another "answer" instead of using the comments. I was a bit surprised by this because he/she has the "Informed" badge, indicating that he/she has *at least* skimmed the Tour. The poster responded politely to my suggestion that the non-answer be deleted, so I get the impression that he/she is legitimately trying to learn and follow the rules.

I decided to look over the Tour (it's been a while since I looked at it) and see if there was anything unclear about what the Answers section is for, and noticed that there isn't a section in the tour that describes how to answer questions or use the Answers box.

I like the Tour overall; it covers almost all aspects of the SO: the overall nature of the site, asking good questions, how reputation works, comments, edits, tags, and badges. But how to *answer* questions and the proper use of the Answer box seems conspicuously absent. Since answers are half of the value of the site, I think it would be worth adding a small section about them.

### Request

I propose that a section with the heading similar to the following be added to the tour after the "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" section:

**Or help provide useful answers to other users' questions**

This block would be modelled after the "...practical, detailed questions" section, with green checkmarks by each item in a list of "Good Answer Guidelines" such as:

- Make sure you've read the question thoroughly and are addressing it specifically
- Be concise
- Partial answers are acceptable, but make sure you describe limitations of your answer
- Write to the best of your ability - grammar, punctuation and spelling count
- Provide context to your links and summarize important linked content

Red X's would appear by items in a list of things to "Avoid in your answers":

- Link-only answers
- Comments - use the comment boxes instead
- Follow-up questions - open a new question instead
- Anything else that isn't an answer to the question

### Justification

It seems to me that the tour is supposed to be a quick, easy-to-read, overview of the help center and how the site works. If that's an accurate statement, then I feel it is incomplete without commenting on how to properly use the answers section. I think this kind of addition could help new users who take the tour make better use of the site without requiring them to explicitly visit the help center to get some introduction to how answers work.

Comment: Agreed. At least there should be some point, what the answer section **certainly isn't meant for** (commenting, asking for clarification, saying thanks, etc.).

Comment: Great and absolutely necessary. Many new users have the "forum" mentality when they start out in SE. A section like this in the tour is important enough to add. I support you!

Comment: This should be on MSE, there's many sites that can benefit from this. Code Review doesn't want code-only answers. Skeptics requires you to source any and all claims you make. I'm not familiar with other sites's answering guidelines... primarily because, well, it's not included in the tour (which I read in full before asking a question on a new site!)

Comment: a new user may not have enough rep to comment. It is common. The bullet points could be added into the answer form itself (deleted on input).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That is common indeed, but that isn't the only type of non-answer I'm looking to prevent with this suggestion. We will never be able to completely stop the "I put it in an answer because I don't have the rep to comment yet" people, but I think my suggestion would help the "I thought this would look better in a bigger box" people, which is what happened in my case. He could have commented on his own post because it's his, and he has a bit over 50 rep anyway. He just thought his reply would be easier to read in an answer box and didn't realize that it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Related: [Is the site tour actually particularly helpful in helping people formulate good questions and answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347969/is-the-site-tour-actually-particularly-helpful-in-helping-people-formulate-good)

Answer (score 5):

I've reposted this question over at Meta Stack Exchange: [Add an "Answering Questions" Section to the Site Tours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242048/273585), after a few modifications to generalize it.

Even though it's now essentially cross-posted, I would like to keep this here until the request is resolved on MSE. It received such a positive response here that I'd like to be able to use this post as evidence that the idea has merit if there is some push-back on MSE.

Comment: Shouldn't this be more of an edit on the question and not an answer? Unless of course you did this as some super meta way to prove your point. :D

Comment: Elsewhere on MSO, when people post feature or burninate requests, people who address those requests will use the answers space to say "Done" or "Request denied because..." It represents a conclusion to the thread. That's the same thing I'm doing here. My answer to my own question is that I'm escalating the request to MSE, so we don't need any more input here. Once it's resolved on MSE, I'm going to post a summary of the outcome and a link to that question.

Comment: No, I'm not smart enough to come of with that kind of plot to make my point.

Comment: If that's the case, then it should be closed here, as cross-posting isn't generally smiled upon. As per [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242048/add-an-answering-questions-section-to-the-site-tours). If you think it's more appropriate somewhere else, ask a mod to move it.

Comment: Agreed. That's what I should have done. I thought about it a bit late, though, which was dumb because I know that cross-posting is generally frowned-upon. I'll flag a moderator to do... some kind of migrating/merging magic.