# How to ask - Too much content for people to read

Tags: feature-request

"How to ask" text box helper can be seen, when user try to ask a new question. Still SO gets low quality questions. That's because a new user doesn't try to read a big chunk of helping information present on "How to ask" page.

I think the information should be less and precise, and also it should act as a quick helper.

Comment: Ok, I agree. What less and precise text do you propose?

Comment: Maybe for inspiration: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258251/lets-improve-the-how-to-ask-pages?rq=1 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page

Comment: Don't disagree with the general sentiment: anything longer than a sentence is too long for some people. But those resources have been worked on, thrown out, rewritten and revised many times, always on a quest for maximum brevity while still telling everything that needs to be told. A concrete suggestion would work much better.

Comment: Well, OK, but then we'd get bad questions and meta posts about insufficient help info :(    Software development is a technically complex area of engineering. and even the small facet of it covered by SO  necessitates a good level of help documentation.   If users don't read it, they should not be in the field at all.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: not to say that, we tend to be the ones saying to "end users" to RTFM. Why wouldn't we do the same when we actually need to comply with some basic etiquette to follow.

Comment: Amazing.. Too many dislikes for my question. I can see suddenly my answers in SO are downvoted even though the answer worked for some people. Infact those answers were posted by me ages ago. The Meta is not a welcoming place as people say, yes i agree this point today.

Comment: Actually, the `How To Ask` text should be comprehensive, well written, well laid out, clear and fully understandable.  Its there as a role model for the way that we expect questions to be written.

Comment: @Pri Keep in mind that Meta downvotes (especially on feature requests) don't have the same meaning as they do on the main site. It's not people being unwelcoming. Downvotes on feature requests basically mean that people don't agree or don't want to see this enacted (which is why I downvoted - I *don't* agree that the "How to Ask" page is too long and I don't want it to be shortened).

Answer (score 16):

I disagree. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is only 795 words, which an average reader should be able to read in about 5 minutes. In addition to that, it's broken up with eight section headings and four bulleted lists for easy skimming. If you try to cut it down any further you'd have to leave out information that would be helpful to those people who do bother to read it. I think the problem is with the readers (or non-readers, I guess), not the content.

Comment: Welcome to the twitter generation, where 140 characters is the maximum we can consume.

Comment: @rene Now I want to rewrite How to Ask as a series of tweets.

Comment: @rene well, unless those 140 characters are absolutely essential for getting homework done by tomorrow, they won't be read :(

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Reading tweets is *all I do* when I have work due the next day. ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard You...you have .. work due IN THE FUTURE?   Wow!  Never happens to me:)

Comment: @Ðаn, would be nice if you posted a Diff file showing what you changed. Your deleted answer is unreadable :)

Comment: @Ðаn, fair enough

Comment: @Ðаn A discussion over whether a particular portion can be removed is a useful discussion to have, as it has a clear, actionable result at the end.  Your statement that there exist some possible changes, without any statement as to what they could be (or why they're merited), isn't particularly useful information.

Comment: @Ðаn I don't know if cutting the text down by 1/8 is significant enough to encourage anyone to actually read it.

Comment: @Ðаn Yeah, I can see your answer. It's still too long, since I'm not going to read that unformatted mess to see what was removed.

Comment: *Now I want to rewrite How to Ask as a series of tweets* I've definitely seen Twitter threads that were longer than 795 words.

Comment: Wll, we cld leve out mst of the vwls, and it wud stll mke snse.  Jst get the amricns to rerite it.

Comment: A good old "tl;dr" reason still plagued till today... you're gracefully right, the problem is in readers themselves, whether they will read or not depends to their mind.

Answer (score 3):

> I think the information should be less and precise, and also it should
>   act as a quick helper.

This already exists on the Ask A Question page:

[image: Screenshot of the Ask A Question page with the How to Ask section circled in red. The placeholder text for the Title and Tags fields are also circled.]

How to Ask already has a shorter explanation of what's on topic and what should be in your question. It's 168 characters, only 32 words. The placeholder text for Title and Tags also have a really brief explanation of what should be there.

There's also the Tour.

We already have things for people who want the bare minimum.

Comment: I think that the tour's [largely useless](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347969/is-the-site-tour-actually-particularly-helpful-in-helping-people-formulate-good) for helping people formulate questions, though.

Comment: @EJoshuaS - It's not enough for creating particularly good questions, no. But the OP is asking for something to give users that won't read the entire help page and the Tour is something short that goes over what type of questions are allowed and what's on/off topic here.

Comment: I think it's only modestly helpful for that, though - there are plenty of off-topic questions that it doesn't talk about

Comment: @EJoshuaS Again, I agree with you. But the question wasn't asking for an in-depth, complete guide. The question was saying we need something shorter than the help page for people who won't read the whole thing.  The argument I'm making in my answer that we already have shorter guides for asking.